# Prove that $f'(0)=L$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f$ be continuous at $0$. Suppose $\displaystyle \lim _{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} =L$. Prove that $f'(0)=L$.

My Work:

$\displaystyle \Bigg|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-L\Bigg|=\Bigg|\frac{f(x)-f(2x)+f(2x)-f(0)}{x}-L\Bigg|$

$\displaystyle \leq \Bigg|\frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}-L\Bigg|+\Bigg|\frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{x}\Bigg|$. Since $f$ is continuous at $0, |f(2x)-f(0)|$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$. Now I want to get rid of $|x|$ of the second term. How can I do it? Can somebody please help me?

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. Define $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\text{ is rational}\\0&\text{if }x\text{ is irrational}\end{cases}$. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac0x=0$, but $f'(0)$ doesn't even exist. EDIT: Didn't see the bit about $f$ being continuous. Derp!

Comment: @columbus8myhw It looks like your $f$ is discontinuous.

Comment: @Mercy Oh, yeah, my bad.

Comment: Let $g(x) = f(x) - f(0) - Lx$ then we can see that $g(2x) - g(x) = f(2x) - f(x) -Lx$ and hence we have $\lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = 0, \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{g(2x) - g(x)}{x} = 0$ and then we can use http://math.stackexchange.com/q/568087/72031 to get $\lim_{x \to 0}(g(x)/x) = 0$ i.e. $f'(0) = L$. The answers by Jimmy and Motyla use the same technique as in linked answer. Also note that the $2$ in $f(2x)$ can be replaced with any $k > 0, k \neq 1$ and result still holds.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be fixed. Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} = L$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $(L-\epsilon)y \le f(2y)-f(y) \le (L+\epsilon)y$ for all $0 < |y| < \delta$.

Since $f(x) - f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^{k-1}}\right)-f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^k}\right)$, by applying the above bounds for $y = \dfrac{x}{2^k}$, we have:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}(L-\epsilon)\dfrac{x}{2^k} \le \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^{k-1}}\right)-f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^k}\right) \le \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n}(L+\epsilon)\dfrac{x}{2^k}$

$(L-\epsilon)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)x \le f(x) - f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) \le (L+\epsilon)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)x$

for all $0 < |x| < \delta$.

Now, what happens if you take the limit as $n \to \infty$?

> In case you didn't see it, I'll work it out. By taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, we get $(L-\epsilon)x \le f(x)-f(0) \le (L+\epsilon)x$ for all $0 < |x| \le \delta$. Hence $f'(0) := \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = L$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Take any $\varepsilon >0$ and let $\delta >0$ be a number such that $$\left| \frac{f(2t) -f(t)}{t} -L\right|\leq \varepsilon $$ for all $|t|\leq \delta .$ Take any $t$ with $0<|t|\leq \delta $ then we have $$\left|\frac{f(t) -f(0)}{t} -L\right | =\left|\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \left(f\left(\frac{t}{2^k} \right) - f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}} \right) \right)}{t}+\frac{f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right) -f(0)}{t} -L\right|\leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\left|\frac{f\left(\frac{t}{2^k} \right) - f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}} \right) }{\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}}-L\right|+\frac{|L|}{2^{n+1}} +\left|\frac{f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right)- f(0)}{t}\right|.$$ Now take $n$ such a big that $2^{-(n+1)}|L|\leq \varepsilon $ and $\left|f\left(\frac{t}{2^{k+1}}\right)- f(0)\right|\leq \varepsilon |t|$ then $$\left|\frac{f(t) -f(0)}{t} -L\right |\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\varepsilon +\varepsilon +\varepsilon <3\varepsilon$$ therefore $f'(0)$ exists.

Comment: how do you ensure $|f(t/2^{k + 1}) - f(0)| \leq \epsilon |t|$? Continuity of $f$ at $0$ allows us to make $f(t) - f(0)$ as small and not $|f(t) - f(0)| \leq \epsilon |t|$. Please see approach of Jimmy's answer which is the proper way to avoid this issue.

Comment: Observe that $t$ is fixed.

Comment: got it, $t$ is dependent on $\epsilon$ but independent of $n$. will upvote.