# Proving that the function is differentiable by using limit.

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

I want to ask about the following problem:

---

Let $f$ be a function defined on the neighborhood of $0$, which is continuous at $x=0$. If $f$ satisfies the following equation, show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and compute $f'(0)$.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{f(x) - f\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{x} = \alpha$$ ($\alpha$ is constant)

---

If one assumes that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, then just by add/subtracting $f(0)$ on the numerator yields an answer $f'(0) = 2\alpha$. So the main problem is the differetiability part.

This is what I've attempted: we can modify the previous limit condition as follows.

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \;\exists \delta > 0 \;s.t \;|x| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) - \alpha x| < \epsilon |x|$

Since $|f(x) - f\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) - \alpha x| = |(f(x) - f(0) -2\alpha ) - (f\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) - f(0)-2\alpha \dfrac{x}{2})|$ holds, we can deduce

$|f(x) - f(0) - 2\alpha | < \epsilon |x| + |f\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) - f(0)-2\alpha \dfrac{x}{2}|$

However, this is far from the conclusion (the right-hand side has to be the form of $K|x|$).

What I've tried from above inequality is repeating this process $m$-times. For instance, if $|x| < \delta$,

$|f(x) - f(0) - 2\alpha | <m\times \epsilon |x| + |f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^m}\right) - f(0)-2\alpha \dfrac{x}{2^m}| < m\times \epsilon |x| + 2\alpha \dfrac{|x|}{2^m}+ |f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^m}\right) - f(0)|$

But also in here, I couldn't find any way to bound $|f\left(\dfrac{x}{2^m}\right) - f(0)|$. (Actually, this can not be generally bounded as continuity does not imply lipschitz continuity)

Any help or comments will be appreciated. I'm quite familiar with Calculus, elementary analysis, and topology.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Without loss of generality you can assume that $f(0) = 0$, and therefore the question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/568087/42969.

Comment: Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1372183/42969.