# $f$ : continuous, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2h)-f(h)}{h}$ if it exists then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous,

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(2h)-f(h)}{h}$ is exist then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$?

If correct, prove.

If not correct, please give me some counterexample.

(This problem is not homework, only my concern... I tried many methods but I don't know it is true or false...)

Comment: have you tried anything yet?  you know you would be more likely to get help if you show you tried.

Comment: You can write $\frac{f(2h)-f(h)}{n}=2\frac{f(2h)-f(0)}{2h}-\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$. Call $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$.

Comment: @Ellusionist I tried many method but all would be not exact. It is very hard. It is not homework(not in any books) and it is just my concern.

Comment: This is a duplicate, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864092/72031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $\varphi(h) = \frac{f(2h) - f(h)}{h}$ for $h \neq 0$ and let $\varphi(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\varphi(h)$. Then notice that for $h \neq 0$ and for $N \geq 1$,

$$ \frac{f(h) - f(2^{-N}h)}{h} = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} 2^{-k} \varphi(2^{-k}h) + 2^{-N}\varphi(2^{-N}h). \tag{*} $$

By the construction we know that $\varphi$ is continuous. Taking $N\to\infty$, this converges to

$$ \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k}\varphi(2^{-k}h) $$

Moreover, for any $\delta > 0$, Weierstrass $M$-test tells that this convergence is in fact uniform over the set $[-\delta, \delta]\setminus\{0\}$. Thus, as $h \to 0$ we can interchange the order of the infinite sum and the limit to find that

$$ \lim_{h\to0} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k}\varphi(2^{-k}h)
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lim_{h\to0} 2^{-k}\varphi(2^{-k}h)
= \varphi(0) $$

Therefore $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0) = \varphi(0)$ as desired.

Comment: Then the argument in my answer is wrong?

Comment: @gimusi, Your argument assumes the existence of $f'(0) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$, but it is not a free gift from OP's setting.

Comment: Could you also give a counter example of this? Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi, A slight tweak of OP's problem does have a counter-example: Notice for $f(x) = |x|$, the limit $$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}$$ exists for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ while $f$ is *not* differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Thank you and I'll read it carefully.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes I lnow of course this classical example but I can'y see it as a counter example in this case.Anyway many tjhanks for you explanation. Bye!

Comment: Is @orole's comment right way for this question, or where is his fault? I just wonder.

Comment: @Domates, As I explained in one of my comments above, existence of $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$ is *not* assumed in OP's setting but rather it is what OP wants to prove.

Comment: @Domates This problem cannot solve by only use some (Stewart) Calculus knowledge, I assure this problem is in connection with sequences {f_n} and some real-analysis knowledge.