# Is $g$ differentiable in $0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

> Let $g$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that:  $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \:\dfrac{g(2x)-g(x)}{x}=l \in \mathbb{R}.$

I am supposed to prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$ and $g'(0)=l$

Here is what I did:
$$\displaystyle\begin{align} \lim_{x \to 0} \:\dfrac{g(2x)-g(x)}{x}&=\lim_{x \to 0}\:\frac{2(g(2x)-g(0))}{2x}-\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}\\&=\lim_{X \to 0}\:2\:\dfrac{g(X)-g(0)}{X} - \lim_{x \to 0}\:\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}\\ &=\lim_{x \to 0}\:\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}\\ &=l  \end{align}$$
Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \:\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x} = l$,
then g is differentiable in $0$ and $g'(0)=l$

Is this valid? I'd appreciate any suggestion thanks.

Comment: How do you know $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$ exists?

Comment: @Anupam You are right I didn't see that, I'll have to think about it more, thanks btw.

Comment: This is wrong. Take for instance $g(x)=x$. Then the limit $l$ is equal to $\frac12$, but $g'(0)=1$. Are you sure you have copied the question correctly?

Comment: @TonyK wait I'll fix it.

Comment: @TonyK: What if $g(x)=1$?

Comment: @TonyK I think it's correct now.

Comment: I have added a simple answer to this question to the slightly more general predecessor question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864058/prove-that-f0-exists-and-f0-b-a-1/3011677#3011677 .