# Does $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x) - f(x/2)}{x} = \ell$ say anything about the convergence of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$?

Tags: calculus

Title pretty much says all.

Of course, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists and is equal to $a$, then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ell &=& \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x/2)}{x} \\
&=& \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} -\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{2} \frac{f(x/2)
}{x/2} \\
&=& a - a/2 = a/2.
\end{eqnarray*}
That is, $a = 2\ell$. Does the existence of the limit $\ell$ ensure the existence of the limit $a$?

Comment: see related question http://math.stackexchange.com/q/568087/72031 which deals with $\lim_{x \to 0}$.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is not unless you add extra conditions on $f$.

For example, define on $(0, \infty)$ the following equivalence relation:
$$x \sim y \Leftrightarrow \frac{x}{y} \in \mathbb Q$$

For this relation you can pick a system $B$ of representatives which is unbounded.

Now, for each $b \in B$ define 
$$f(x)=b \mbox { whenever } x \sim b$$

For this function you always have $f(x)=f(x/2)$.

But since $B$ is unbounded, you can find a sequence $b_n \in B$ such that $b_n \to \infty$.

Then
$$b_n \to \infty \mbox{ and } \lim_n \frac{f(b_n)}{b_n}=1$$
while
$$n \to \infty   \mbox{ and } \lim_n \frac{f(n)}{n}= \lim_n \frac{f(1)}{n}=0$$

To eliminate this counterexample, you need to assume that $f$ is at least continuous, maybe differentiable would bea good extra condition.

Comment: @Angelo Well, if $f$ is bounded, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} =0$ regardless of if $f$ satisfies the given condition or not.

Comment: It is not necessary that $f$ is a continuous function, in fact it is sufficient that $\cfrac{f(x)}{x}$ is bounded on $[a,+\infty[$ where $a>0$ that is $|f(x)|\le Mx\;$ for all $x\in [a,+\infty[$.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is your function, then $\cfrac{f(x)}{x}$ is not bounded. To prove it, we proceed as follows: since $B$ is unbounded, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $b_n^*\in B$ such that $b_n^*>n$, moreover we consider the sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\left\{\cfrac{b_n^*}{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subsetneq\left[1,+\infty\right[\;$. It results that $\cfrac{f(x_n)}{x_n}=n\;$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so $\cfrac{f(x)}{x}$ is not bounded on $\left[1,+\infty\right[$.

Answer (score 3):

**Theorem 1:**

If $\;g:\left[0,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ is a continuous function on $\left[0,+\infty\right[,$

$\alpha\;$ is a positive real number different from $1\; (\alpha>0,\;\alpha\ne1)$

and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\alpha g(\alpha x)\big]=l\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

then there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

**Proof:**

Let $\;\beta=
  \begin{cases}
    \alpha & \text{if }\;0<\alpha<1 \\
    \cfrac{1}{\alpha} & \text{if }\;\alpha>1
  \end{cases}\;.\;\;$ It results that $\;0<\beta<1.$

We are going to prove that

$\cfrac{1}{1-\beta}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\beta g(\beta x)\big]=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

The previous equality is evidently true if $\;\beta=\alpha\;.$

If $\;\beta=\frac{1}{\alpha}\;,\;$ it follows that

$\frac{1}{1-\beta}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\beta g(\beta x)\big]=$

$=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\frac{1}{\alpha} g\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)\big]=$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[\alpha g(x)-g\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)\big]=$

$=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)-\alpha g(x)\big]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by letting } X=\frac{x}{\alpha}\;}}{=}\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\lim\limits_{X\to+\infty}\big[g(X)-\alpha g(\alpha X)\big]=\frac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

Moreover,

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k}\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]=g(x)-\beta^{k+1} g\left(\beta^{k+1} x\right)$

for all $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;$ and for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}\;.$

For any $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;$, since $\;\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left(\beta^{k+1}x\right)=0\;$ and the function $\;g\;$ is continuous at the point $x_0=0\;,\;$ we get that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}g\left(\beta^{k+1}x\right)=g(0)\;,\;$ consequently,

$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\big[g(x)-\beta^{k+1} g\left(\beta^{k+1} x\right)\big]=g(x)\;,\;\;\;\;\forall\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[.$

Therefore,

$g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

for all $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;.$

Since the function $\;g(x)-\beta g(\beta x)\;$ is continuous on $\left[0,+\infty\right[$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\beta g(\beta x)\big]\underset{\overbrace{\text{ from }(*)\;}}{=}\cfrac{l(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha}\in\mathbb{R}\;,\;$

there exists $\;M>0\;$ such that

$\big|g(x)-\beta g(\beta x)\big|\le M\;,\quad$ for all $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;,\;$ hence,

$\big|g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big|\le M\;,\;\;\forall x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;$ and $\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So the sequence $\;\big\{\beta^n M\big\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ of positive real numbers satisfies the following conditions:

$\bigg|\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]\bigg|\le \beta^n M$,

$\forall x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;$ and $\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(\beta^n M\big)=\cfrac{M}{1-\beta}\in\mathbb{R}^+\;.$

By applying the Weierstrass M-test, we get that the series $(**)$ is uniformly convergent on $\left[0,+\infty\right[,\;$ consequently

$\exists\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{ for the uniform convergence }}}{=}\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by letting } X=\beta^n x\;}}{=}\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\lim\limits_{X\to+\infty}\beta^n\big[g(X)-\beta g(\beta X)\big]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{ from }(*)\;}}{=}\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^n\cfrac{l(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha}=\cfrac{l(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^n=$

$=\cfrac{l(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha}\cdot\cfrac{1}{1-\beta}=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

---

**Corollary 1:**

If $\;g:\left[a,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ is a continuous function on $\left[a,+\infty\right[,$

$\alpha\;$ is a positive real number different from $1\; (\alpha>0,\;\alpha\ne1)$

and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\alpha g(\alpha x)\big]=l\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

then there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

**Proof:**

If $\;a\le0\;$ the restriction $\;g\big|_{\left[0,+\infty\right[}\;$ of the function $g$ to $\left[0,+\infty\right[$ satisfies all the hypotheses of the previous theorem, so there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g\big|_{\left[0,+\infty\right[}=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

If $\;a>0\;$ we consider the function $\;G:\left[0,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ defined as

$G(x)= \begin{cases}
    g(a) & \text{if }\;0\le x<a\\
    g(x) & \text{if }\;x\ge a
  \end{cases}\;.$

The function $\;G\;$ satisfies all the hypotheses of the previous theorem, so there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}G(x)=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

---

**Corollary 2:**

If $\;a\;$ is a positive real number $\;(a>0)\;,$

$f:\left[a,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ is a continuous function on $\left[a,+\infty\right[,$

$\alpha\;$ is a positive real number different from $1\; (\alpha>0,\;\alpha\ne1)$

and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cfrac{f(x)-f(\alpha x)}{x}=l\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

then there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cfrac{f(x)}{x}=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

**Proof:**

We consider the function $\;g:\left[a,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ defined as

$g(x)=\cfrac{f(x)}{x}\quad$ for all $\;x\in\left[a,+\infty\right[\;.$

The function $\;g(x)\;$ is continuous on $\;\left[a,+\infty\right[\;$ and

$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\alpha g(\alpha x)\big]=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left[\cfrac{f(x)}{x}-\alpha\cfrac{f(\alpha x)}{\alpha x}\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cfrac{f(x)-f(\alpha x)}{x}=l\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

The function $\;g(x)\;$ satisfies all the hypotheses of Corollary 1, so there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cfrac{f(x)}{x}= \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

Answer (score 0):

$\color{blue}{\text{It is not necessary that the function } g \text{ is continuous,}}\\\color{blue}{\text{in fact it is sufficient that it is bounded.}}$

**Theorem 2:**

If $\;g:\left[0,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ is a bounded function on $\left[0,+\infty\right[,$

$\alpha\;$ is a positive real number different from $1\; (\alpha>0,\;\alpha\ne1)$

and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\alpha g(\alpha x)\big]=l\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

then there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

**Proof:**

Let $\;\beta=
  \begin{cases}
    \alpha & \text{if }\;0<\alpha<1 \\
    \cfrac{1}{\alpha} & \text{if }\;\alpha>1
  \end{cases}\;.\;\;$ It results that $\;0<\beta<1.$

We are going to prove that

$\cfrac{1}{1-\beta}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\beta g(\beta x)\big]=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

The previous equality is evidently true if $\;\beta=\alpha\;.$

If $\;\beta=\frac{1}{\alpha}\;,\;$ it follows that

$\frac{1}{1-\beta}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\beta g(\beta x)\big]=$

$=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\frac{1}{\alpha} g\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)\big]=$

$=\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[\alpha g(x)-g\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)\big]=$

$=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)-\alpha g(x)\big]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by letting } X=\frac{x}{\alpha}\;}}{=}\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\lim\limits_{X\to+\infty}\big[g(X)-\alpha g(\alpha X)\big]=\frac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

Moreover,

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k}\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]=g(x)-\beta^{k+1} g\left(\beta^{k+1} x\right)$

for all $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;$ and for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}\;.$

Given that the function $\;g\;$ is bounded on $\;\left[0,+\infty\right[,\;$ there exists $\;M>0\;$ such that

$\left|g(x)\right|\le M\;$ for all $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;.$

Since $\;\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\beta^{k+1}=0\;$ and $\;\left|g\left(\beta^{k+1} x\right)\right|\le M\;$ for all $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;$ and for all $\;k\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;$ we get that

$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\big[g(x)-\beta^{k+1} g\left(\beta^{k+1} x\right)\big]=g(x)\;,\;\;\;\;\forall\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[.$

Therefore,

$g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

for all $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;.$

Moreover,

$\big|g(x)-\beta g(\beta x)\big|\le \big|g(x)\big|+\beta\big|g(\beta x)\big|\le M+\beta M=N\in\mathbb{R}^+\;,$

for all $\;x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;,\;$ hence,

$\big|g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big|\le N\;,\;\;\forall x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;$ and $\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So the sequence $\;\big\{\beta^n N\big\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ of positive real numbers satisfies the following conditions:

$\bigg|\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]\bigg|\le \beta^n N$,

$\forall x\in\left[0,+\infty\right[\;$ and $\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(\beta^n N\big)=\cfrac{N}{1-\beta}\in\mathbb{R}^+\;.$

By applying the Weierstrass M-test, we get that the series $(**)$ is uniformly convergent on $\left[0,+\infty\right[,\;$ consequently

$\exists\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{ for the uniform convergence }}}{=}\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\beta^n\big[g\left(\beta^n x\right)-\beta g\left(\beta^{n+1} x\right)\big]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{ by letting } X=\beta^n x\;}}{=}\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\lim\limits_{X\to+\infty}\beta^n\big[g(X)-\beta g(\beta X)\big]=$

$\underset{\overbrace{\text{ from }(*)\;}}{=}\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^n\cfrac{l(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha}=\cfrac{l(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^n=$

$=\cfrac{l(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha}\cdot\cfrac{1}{1-\beta}=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

---

**Corollary 3:**

If $\;g:\left[a,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ is a bounded function on $\left[a,+\infty\right[,$

$\alpha\;$ is a positive real number different from $1\; (\alpha>0,\;\alpha\ne1)$

and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\alpha g(\alpha x)\big]=l\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

then there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

**Proof:**

If $\;a\le0\;$ the restriction $\;g\big|_{\left[0,+\infty\right[}\;$ of the function $g$ to $\left[0,+\infty\right[$ satisfies all the hypotheses of the previous theorem, so there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g\big|_{\left[0,+\infty\right[}=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

If $\;a>0\;$ we consider the function $\;G:\left[0,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ defined as

$G(x)= \begin{cases}
    g(a) & \text{if }\;0\le x<a\\
    g(x) & \text{if }\;x\ge a
  \end{cases}\;.$

The function $\;G\;$ satisfies all the hypotheses of the previous theorem, so there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}G(x)=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

---

**Corollary 4:**

If $\;f:\left[a,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ is a function on $\left[a,+\infty\right[$ where $a>0$,

$M$ is a positive real number $(M>0)$ such that

$\;\big|f(x)\big|\le Mx\;\;$ for all $\;x\in\left[a,+\infty\right[,$

$\alpha\;$ is a positive real number different from $1\; (\alpha>0,\;\alpha\ne1)$

and $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cfrac{f(x)-f(\alpha x)}{x}=l\in\mathbb{R}\;,$

then there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cfrac{f(x)}{x}=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$

**Proof:**

We consider the function $\;g:\left[a,+\infty\right[\to\mathbb{R}\;$ defined as

$g(x)=\cfrac{f(x)}{x}\quad$ for all $\;x\in\left[a,+\infty\right[\;.$

It results that

$\big|g(x)\big|=\cfrac{\big|f(x)\big|}{x}\le M\quad$ for all $\;x\in\left[a,+\infty\right[\;.$

So the function $\;g(x)\;$ is bounded on $\;\left[a,+\infty\right[\;$ and

$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\big[g(x)-\alpha g(\alpha x)\big]=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left[\cfrac{f(x)}{x}-\alpha\cfrac{f(\alpha x)}{\alpha x}\right]=$

$=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cfrac{f(x)-f(\alpha x)}{x}=l\in\mathbb{R}\;.$

Thus, the function $\;g(x)\;$ satisfies all the hypotheses of Corollary 3, hence there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\cfrac{f(x)}{x}= \lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}g(x)=\cfrac{l}{1-\alpha}\;.$