# $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} = l < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

- $f$ is continuous on $0$
- $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} = l < \infty$
- We want to show that $f$ is derivable on $0$

---

My attempt :
We could try to control

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{f(x)-f(\dfrac{x}{2^{n+1}})}{x} - \sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{l}{2^{k+1}} \right|&=
\sum_{k=0}^n \left|\dfrac{ f(\dfrac{x}{2^{n+1}})-f(\dfrac{x}{2^{n+1}})   }{x} - \dfrac{l}{2^{k+1}}  \right| < n \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Comment: Also similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/568087/42969

Comment: Thanks, it solves the question.